# How to pluck data for a form

Tags: laravel

I'd like to show names on my select dropdown

I have 3 tables: 'users','users_pro' and 'practice'

> **users** : id ,name ,dob ,.. etc
>
> **users_pro** : id ,user_id,..etc
>
> **practice** : id , user_pro_id ,...etc

I want to input data to table 'practice' and I want to make a select dropdown using pluck on **users_pro** with **users** like this :

```
public function input_practice()
{
    $data= Users_pro::with('users')->get()->pluck('id','user_id');
    
    dd($data);
    // return view('admin.input.input_riwayat_kgb',
    // [
    // 'data'=>$data,
    

    // ]);
}
```

If I dd($data), I get :

```
    Collection {#327 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    6 => 3 // 6 is user_id ,and 3 is 'id' on users_pro , i need to show 'name' like 3 => 'jhon'
    13 => 4
    12 => 5
    14 => 6
  ]
}
```

But I want to show the name of the user on my select dropdown.  Can someone help me?

Comment: I removed the old answer with the huge comment list.  Let's try this from the other side - it will be much easier.  See new answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull a collection and then get the name and id from the relationship models within.  Thus, you will get an error that the property does not exist on the *collection* because it is many **User_pro** objects and then tries to get user data from each one of the relations would require a loop.

Assuming you have a `users` relationship set up on the **User_pro** model, you can get your dropdown list like this:

```
 $data= User::whereHas('user_pro')->pluck('name','id');
```

This gives you a collection of users (who happen to be pros) and then plucks the `name` and `id` *of your users* for you to use in your dropdown.

Comment: this pluck is ('id','user_id'); , how i can display this name sir ?

Comment: this DD just showing Collection {#318 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    6 => 3
    12 => 5
    13 => 4
    14 => 6
  ]
}

Comment: Shouldn't.  Did you use this: `$data= User::whereHas('user_pro')->pluck('name','id');` ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_pro_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `id`, `name` from `users` where exists (select * from `user_pro` where `users`.`user_pro_id` = `user_pro`.`id`))

Comment: You don't have your database set up in Laravel standard way - either change them or add the FK to the relationship explicitly.  This solution will then work correctly.

Comment: omg , this is have FK , user_id is FK from users , user_pro_id is FK from user_pro . your query output is same like my query at this thread sir, i dont know

Comment: if i build like this $data= Users_pro::whereHas('users')->pluck('id','user_id'); its dont have error .

Comment: but if i build $data= User::whereHas('users_pro')->pluck('id','nama'); its have error like SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_pro_id ......

Comment: You don't have your relationship setup on users for User Pro.  You don't have user_pro_id on User table - look at the beginning of your own post - you don't have the right foreign key to make this work.  Add user_pro_id to the users table and set the relationship.  Once you have the relationship correct, the solution in this answer will work and you will get name and id.  Until you have the right FK and relationship, this will fail.

Comment: hmmm , my relation is on Model users_pro , to user . public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class ,'user_id');
        
    }

Comment: No, for this to work to get what you want, you need the relation to be on the **User** model.  But to do that you need to have the FK user_pro_id on the database, which you don't yet.

Comment: so i cant showed this data with this my database setup ? i cant changed my db sir . i dont know ,i have acces FK user_id , usually i can access users FK like this . $users->masters->name_master  , but on this pluck cant access like $users->users_pro->status_user_pro

Comment: on my thread i have a Collection {#327 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    6 => 3 // 6 is user_id ,and 3 is 'id' on users_pro , i need to show 'name' like 3 => 'jhon'
    13 => 4
    12 => 5
    14 => 6
  ]
} . its user_id and id , can i access users like $data->users->name on my pluck

Comment: No, you really need to study a bit on how the relationship works in Laravel.  This won't work as you have it right now for the reasons I put in the answer.  You either need to change the DB or write a new set of model relationships to get what you want.  Or, I suppose you could do some convoluted queries, but this is a one-line solution (like I put in the answer), if you can fix your architecture.

Answer (score -1):

This is solved with this line :

```
$data = Users_pro::with('users')->get()->pluck('users.nama', 'id');
```